# How to fix overlapping in grid?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As you can see in the screenshot below, the boxes in second row are overlapping the ones in the first row. I've tried many alternatives but none have worked so far.

Here is a screenshot,

[image]

My code for placement of the boxes,

```
UIButton *btnWordBox = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(nUpWidth*26+(316-26*WordCount)/2, nRowHeight, 26, 35)];
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: calculate 'y' while setting frame for your button, try with increase its value.for example nRowHeight+10

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIButton *btnWordBox = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(nUpWidth*26+(316-26*WordCount)/2, nRowHeight+20, 26, 35)];
```